# Change the height of a view added dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-custom-view

I am working in an android and I am adding a view dynamically to a linear layout. And I get the height of the view added dynamically from `ViewTreeObserver`, but after I set the height pragmatically inside the `ViewTreeObserver` it does't change. Please look into my code

onCreate

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.wwww);

            ScrollView parentScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.parentscroll);

            parentScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    findViewById(R.id.subscroll).getParent()
                            .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    return false;
                }
            });

            ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.subscroll))
                    .setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                            return false;
                        }
                    });

            new TESTT().execute();

            final LinearLayout tv = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.subscrollLinearLayout);
            ViewTreeObserver vto = tv.getViewTreeObserver();
            vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                public void onGlobalLayout() {


            if (tv.getChildAt(0) != null) {
                int btnsize = tv.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
                ScrollView scrolllayout = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.subscroll);
                scrolllayout.getLayoutParams().height = btnsize * 2;
            }

                }
            });        
        }
```

#### AsyncTask :

```
private class TESTT extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(4000);//Time taken to consume the web service. If there
                                  // is no delay the code work correct
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);


            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.subscrollLinearLayout);
            List<String> mSempLog = new ArrayList<String>();

            mSempLog.add("TEST1");
            mSempLog.add("TEST2");
            mSempLog.add("TEST3");
            mSempLog.add("TEST4");
            mSempLog.add("TEST5");
            mSempLog.add("TEST6");
            mSempLog.add("TEST7");
            mSempLog.add("TEST8");



            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                LinearLayout service_row = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.summary_list_row, null);

                TextView mServiceSlNo = (TextView) service_row
                        .findViewById(R.id.summary_list_textslNo);

                TextView mServiceText = (TextView) service_row
                        .findViewById(R.id.summary_list_textService);

                TextView mStartDate = (TextView) service_row
                        .findViewById(R.id.summaryview_list_initiated_text);

                TextView mEndDate = (TextView) service_row
                        .findViewById(R.id.summaryview_list_completed_text);

                TextView mFullyEngaged = (TextView) service_row
                        .findViewById(R.id.summaryview_fully_count_text);

                TextView mProgress = (TextView) service_row
                        .findViewById(R.id.summaryview_listentry_TextView);

                LinearLayout mServiceLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) service_row
                        .findViewById(R.id.summary_list_sercicelayout);

                mServiceSlNo.setText(Integer.toString(i + 1) + ".");
                mServiceText.setText("fdgdfgdfg");
                mStartDate.setText("fdgdfgdfg");

                mFullyEngaged.setText("fdgdfgdfg");

                mServiceLinearLayout.setTag(i);
                layout.addView(service_row, i);

            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

what ever you want to add has some layout , make it in layout.xml file

and use this approach to add a new View in your parent layout.

```
LinearLayout lay_toAddItems = (LinearLayout) rootView
                        .findViewById(R.id.lay_toAddItems);
View hiddenInfo = orderDetails.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                        R.layout.include_items_invieworder, lay_toAddItems,
                        false);
lay_toAddItems.addView(hiddenInfo);
```

- rootview = parentLayout.
- lay_toAddItems = in which you want to add
- new view include_items_invieworder = your new layout.

**Edited Section** :

```
LinearLayout layoutDialog = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay_forgotpassword);

layoutDialog.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(dialogWidth*3/4+dialogWidth*1/8,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but your answer doesn't match my question.

Comment: why , yaar i have used this approach in my project.